# How can I rearrange the order of y-axis on cleveland dot plot?

Tags: r, sorting, dot-plot

I have a [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F88Xa.png) and I generated a
[Hallmark Cleveland plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOqPd.png) to visualize the enrichment scores before and after applying my software. But how can I rearrange the order of my plot to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuGMW.png) ? I was thinking to sum up scores of all statuses in each hallmark and plot the hallmarks in a descending order based on the sum of status scores. But I am not sure how to do it. T

The code is as follows

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Table, aes(Table$`Enrichment Scores`, Table$Hallmarks)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Table$Status)) + 
    ggtitle("Hallmarks") + geom_line(aes(group = Table$Hallmarks)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = ES_cutoff, color = "blue", linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a little made-up data, you could use `fct_reorder` to reorder the `hallmarks` based on the `distance` of the scores for that hallmark from the cut-off.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Made-up data
df <- tribble(~hallmarks, ~scores, ~status,
        "a", 10, "x",
        "a", 12, "x",
        "a", 14, "x",
        "b", 30, "x",
        "b", 31, "x",
        "b", 32, "x",
        "c", 20, "y",
        "c", 22, "y",
        "c", 26, "y",
        "d", 40, "y",
        "d", 39, "y",
        "d", 41, "y",
        "e", 30, "y",
        "e", 40, "y",
        "e", 60, "y"     
) 

cut_off <- 30

df |> 
  group_by(hallmarks) |> 
  mutate(distance = if_else(min(scores) >= cut_off, 
                            min(scores) - cut_off, max(scores) - cut_off)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(scores, fct_reorder(hallmarks, distance), color= status)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = status)) + 
  ggtitle("Hallmarks") + 
  geom_line(aes(group = hallmarks)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = cut_off, color = "blue", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  labs(y = "Hallmarks")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Answer you very much Carl! Do you know how to re-order the hallmarks in the same way as you did, but i want to group the hallmarks that overlapped with the cutoff line together. Sort by mean does not allow me to have the grouped hallmarked placed in the middle of the cleveland dotplot

Comment: See if this works for you.